# How to dynamically register new attributes to ActiveRecord model on Rails on Running time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've altered the database adding a new column 'email' to the table contacts by an action from another controller. I want now to add this as a new attribute to the ActiveRecord model Contact, how can i do that? Or is there another way to add a new attribute and changing the table all in one time? This operations is all on running time that is why I've putted dynamically.

I tried doing that but i receive the error

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ContactsController#create`

on `@contact = Contact.new(contact_params)` but when i restart the application it all works out ok, it seems that the model instance needs a new remap of the database schema or something like that

Comment: Changing your database schema in the runtime seems like bad bad idea, unless you are making database management web app.

Comment: Its a admin type of application so the changing of schema is necessary, any tips on that I would be very welcome to hear

Answer (score 1):

That was in deed the problem, i had to use the following method `reset_column_information`

Here is the sequence:

`Contact.reset_column_information()
@contact = Contact.new(contact_params)`